# OSX sending/receiving data via USB/Serial

Tags: cocoa, usb, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, usbserial

I need to write a cocoa app (lion and mountain lion) to transfer (send/receive) data with a serial device attached to the USB port.

I have spent some time studying the osx documentation (i/o kit) and I have googled for tutorials, but with not much success.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial and some sample code ?

Thank you for any help.